# SAP WEB IDE - Deploying to another Sub Account

Tags: sap-web-ide

Since switching to a custom Identity Provider, we can no longer deploy apps to our test sub-account.

if this is not possible with custom IDP's what is the workaround?

Comment: It is possible. We are running it with custom IDP. Can't remember if there is some specific configuration though. "PropagageAccount" is set on the destination?

Comment: Which destination exactly?

Comment: "webide_di" destination.

Comment: Thank you. PropagateAccount is already set for the webide_di DESTINATION.

Comment: Did you solve it? The other thing I remember we did was adding a couple of assertion-based attributes to the Application Identity Provider. We mapped first_name, mail, display_name and last_name to their principal attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer from SAP is this can't be done with more than one sub-account.  The workaround is to import the export apps as HTML applications in the other sub-account, which serves the same purpose as deploying.